# How to bulk edit user fields with different values?

Tags: views, users

I'm trying to mass edit users and user field values. And I'm struggling.

I have a custom view with custom fields and filters that lists me users I wish to edit. Now I tried the [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module but this only allows to start a bulk operation on a field setting all users field values to the same value.

Now what I need is a way to edit the same field across all users but with induvidual values on a per-user basis. I dont want to open 1000+ profiles and find the field in each profile edit form to modify and save it but to mass edit this field for all users at once.

I have views inline editing in my mind, or a view which works like an excel sheet. But most solutions ([Editable Views](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews), [Editable Fields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields), [Views Megarow](https://drupal.org/project/views_megarow), ...) are not working at all or are very limited to special fields or views or content types or whatever.

**Example:**

Imagine a simple example view which lists users and some of their fields.

```
[ ] Uid   Name   Gender   Age   Relation
------------------------------------------------
[ ] 0     Root                  Admin      Edit
[x] 1     Lea    f        27    Friend     Edit
[x] 2     Dad    m        26    Family     Edit
[ ] ...
```

Now I selected two users because I want to change their taxonomy reference 'Relation'. And want to get another view which looks like that, listing only the users I selected and the fields I whish to edit:

```
User   Select Relation
------------------------------
Lea    [Friend][^]
Dad    [Family][^]
                       [Save]
```

**Scope:**

Did anyone ever had such a usecase and know of any solution? As I mentioned, VBO gets close to this behaviour but does not

1. work with taxonomy term references,
2. allow unique values on a per-user base.

Comment: Have you tried using the feeds module - https://drupal.org/project/feeds for this? I know from previous experience you can update existing nodes, haven't tried it on users but their documentation says its works with users.

Comment: editableviews is your best bet

Comment: @NigelWaters thanks that one is the best choice indeed.